# How to check in linq if the list is null?

Tags: c#, linq

i am binding a checked list box with following ling that retrun a list list, but if the list is empty how should i manage it?
It throws exception in the ling statment and if null what should i set for checkedlist box

```
public List<dataObject> GetAllCustomItems(CategoryType currType, int mCategoryID)
        {
            List<dataObject> lst = null;
            try
            {
                switch (currType)
                {
                    case CategoryType.Dressing:
                        lst = (from xx in this.DressingItems 
                               where xx.DressingInfo.CatID == mCategoryID 
                               select new dataObject() { 
                                   ID = xx.DressingInfo.DressingID,
                                   Name = xx.DressingInfo.Description, 
                                   Selected = xx.IsDefault 
                               }).ToList();
                        break;
              }
        }
```

It throws exception

```
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source
```

Comment: Are you sure `this.DressingItems` is not null or empty? `if (this.DressingItems != null && this.DressingItems.any) {...`

Comment: actually no dressing item exist..

Comment: Is it `DressingInfo` that is sometimes null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think is xx.DressingInfo object problems cause it will come out Object reference not found first, sure is the values from xx.DressingInfo got problems. you can try iif to check it.

```
  var lst = (from xx in this.DressingItems 
                           where xx.DressingInfo.CatID == mCategoryID 
                           select new dataObject() { 
                               ID = xx.DressingInfo.DressingID==null?0:xx.DressingInfo.DressingID,
                               Name = xx.DressingInfo.Description==null? "":xx.DressingInfo.Description, 
                               Selected = xx.IsDefault 
                           });
return IsNullThenNew<dataObject>(lst);
```

If you don't want to return null back to caller, you can return at least empty object by generic method below.

```
 public static bool IsNullOrEmpty<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
        {
            return enumerable == null || !enumerable.Any();
        }
 public static List<T> IsNullThenNew<T>(this IEnumerable<T> t)
        {
            if (!IsNullOrEmpty<T>(t))
            {
                return t.ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                Type genericListType = typeof(List<>);
                Type listType = genericListType.MakeGenericType(t.GetType());
                object listInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(listType);
                return (List<T>)listInstance;
            }//end if-else
        }
```

Comment: DressingInfo was not getting populated.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure `this.DressingItems` is not null or empty?

Check that before your LINQ query:

```
if (this.DressingItems != null && this.DressingItems.Any()) {
    lst = (from xx in this.DressingItems where...
}
```

Let the `lst` return null if `DressingItems` is null or empty.

**Edit**: (after the op comment)

Also, check the DressingInfo property:

```
where xx.DressingInfo != null &&...
```

Answer (score 1):

How about checking DressingInfo for null first in the where clause

```
where xx.DressingInfo != null && xx.DressingInfo.CatID == mCategoryID
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change `List<dataObject> lst = null;`
to `List<dataObject> lst = new List<dataObject>`;
Or do something like this:

```
public List<dataObject> GetAllCustomItems(CategoryType currType, int mCategoryID)
{
    try
    {
        switch (currType)
        {
            case CategoryType.Dressing:
                List<dataObject> lst = (from xx in this.DressingItems 
                       where xx.DressingInfo.CatID == mCategoryID 
                       select new dataObject() { 
                           ID = xx.DressingInfo.DressingID,
                           Name = xx.DressingInfo.Description, 
                           Selected = xx.IsDefault 
                       }).ToList();
                break;
      }
}
```